# Enable Bluetooth Adapter for BeagleBone Black

Tags: bluetooth, debian, beagleboneblack, lsusb, connman

I recently bought a [USB 2.0 Bluetooth Adapter](http://plugable.com/products/usb-bt4le). It claims to have support from Linux kernels of versions 3.4 and higher. I have a **BeagleBone Black** with **Debian GNU/Linux 7** image and kernel 3.8. I am developing on BeagleBone Black by hosting it through USB with `ssh`.

I have tried both hot plugging and  plugging in before boot and failed.

Then, I tried [this tutorial](http://michaelhleonard.com/enable-bluetooth-on-beaglebone-black/). However, I cannot find the `connman` directory on my BeagleBone Black device. I looked up and assumed I needed to install the `connman` package, but my BeagleBone Black has no internet access.

I have also tried `lsusb -v`, as suggested by an answer of a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754699/usb-bluetooth-dongle-isnt-recognized-by-beaglebone-black) to this, with no luck. The weird thing is, while `lsusb` itself prints

> Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
>   Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

`lsusb -v` only prints

> Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

then hangs. Information regarding bus 002, which I believe the device is connected to, is not printed. I have to restart the `ssh` connection to get back to work.

How should I approach to get the dongle to work on my BeagleBone Black? If the `connman` package is sufficient, how do I install it on my BeagleBone Black without internet access. Why does `lsusb -v` hang?

Any help is appreciated!

UPDATE:

The actual problem turned out to be that my BeagleBone Black is flawed/damaged. I plugged the Bluetooth Adapter into a plain new BeagleBone Black before powering it, and the Bluetooth Adapter is recognized! Not only does `lsusb` prints out the adapter info, but also `lsusb -v` does not hang at all. The overall performance of the new board (boot time, compilation time, execution time) is also several times better. I suspect that it was due to the various improper power-off.

In case anyone is just as careless, the BeagleBone Black **SHALL** be powered off by:

- Holding down the power button for about 8 seconds then releasing it.
- Using `halt` or `shutdown -h now` command in the Userspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have possible 4 solutions for you:

1) download the connman package and save it to a usb flashdrive. Connect the flashdrive to the beaglebone and install the package using the following command: dpkg -i {.deb package}.

2) download the connman package on your desktop computer and ssh into your beaglebone. once you ssh in you could copy the file trough ssh using scp. Note the syntax $ scp your_username@remotehost.edu:foobar.txt /some/local/directory. Then install the connman package using dpkg -i {.deb package}.

3) share your desktop computers internet connection with the beaglebone and ssh into the beaglebone. Download the package directly using apt-get or wget whatever tool you prefer.

4) connect your beaglebone to your router using rj-45 cable. Maybe this is not your preferred solution but it's easy and after port forwarding you will have access to your beaglebone from anywhere.

Hope this helps and note that I never used a bluetooth adapter with a BBB. I'm just giving generic instructions on your general problem.

Comment: Thanks much! I'll try these options and report my progress.

Comment: I fixed it! The problem has nothing to do with what I asked, but I'll mark yours as accepted answer anyway. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. Being curious, what was the problem?

Comment: Oh i've updated my question with the actual problem and my solution. See above! :)